# How to call transfer to use callerId from AppTapi.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I have used the addtapi.net tool and the setup is ready and I get the callerid from incoming call. But I do not know how to transfer a callerid call ?

I have used the code below:

```
TapiCall consultationCall = activeCall.SetupTransfer();  
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);  
if (consultationCall.State != TapiCallState.DialTone) 
    throw new Exception("Call state is not Dialtone");  
consultationCall.Dial("201"); 
// When the state of the consultation call changes to Connected,
// the user can talk to ext. 201
// before transferring the remote party to ext. 201
...
// Second step: complete the transfer   
activeCall.CompleteTransfer(consultationCall, false);
```

but the call does not transfer to the 201 extension.